# How to connect to a website using the headers which browser sent?

Tags: java, android, sockets, socketserver

I'm using socketserver on java and listening to port 8080, and my browser sends me header Infos. So how can I retrieve a Web page using this headers with my injected headers?

Comment: Could you explain that with more details? I don't understand your question. [ask]

Comment: @zapl Okay then, http://www.datafilehost.com/d/d439b2c7 This is a project that similar to mine. It gets response from browser, connects to the requested url, gets data and sends to browser back. I need a similar code to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
((WebView)view).getSettings().setUserAgentString("like in browser");
```

Comment: Well, I don't want to open a webview. I will send response to a browser (for example Opera)